# How to solve for effective interest rate of a government bond on HP 10bll+ financial calculator?

Tags: interest

Price of bond = 100.44
Nominal coupon interest rate (compounded annually) = 1.5%
Duration: 10 years
Face value (what you get back after 10 years, may be poor translation): 100

Spent hours now trying to figure out how I solve for the effective interest rate, and some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for the Yield to Maturity

Press [C ALL] to remove any result already stored.

You have to use the top 5 buttons on the calculator to enter the maturity, the price (as a negative), the coupon and the face value:

10 [N]
-100.44 [PV]
1.5 [PMT]
100 [FV]

Press [I/YR] the result 1.45209173 is displayed. This can be rounded to 1.45%.

Comment: THANK YOU! Words can't express how grateful I am!